# SQL Sub Query not working

Tags: sql

Any idea why this doesn't work then (based on your examples on forum it should!) Thanks.

```
select result.low 
from (
  select top 1 country as low, count() 
  from customers c, orders o 
  where c.customerid=o.customerid 
  group by country 
  order by count()
) as result
```

Comment: You have multiple problems . . . `count()` with no argument, and a subquery with no name for a column, among others.  In addition, you are using old-style join syntax.

Comment: Could you please turn your post into the form of a acceptable question? What is it you are trying to accomplish in this query?

Comment: Nitpicking: that's not a sub-query it's "derived table".

Answer (score 0):

as has been stated there are several issues

```
select result.low 
from (
  select top 1 country as low, count() -- count() needs an argument and needs to be aliased
  from customers c, orders o           -- old style join
  where c.customerid=o.customerid      
  group by country                     -- column `country` may need qualifying
  order by count()                     -- count() needs an argument
) as result
```

so the query should probably be

```
select top 1 country as low
from customers c
join orders o 
on c.customerid=o.customerid 
group by c.country
order by count(*)
```